# python thousands separator formatting with different character without using locale

Tags: python, string

I am looking to format thousands with an apostrophe (but could be something else) without using locale or a replace method.

The comma that is used by default in the string formatting must be defined somewhere in the Python source code but I can't find where.  Is it possible to access it and change it once so that all formatting in the same session uses the new character?

To be clear (edit after @Matiss comment), I do not want to change the formatting syntax. It should stay as f"{value:,}".  However, instead of inserting commas, I would like to insert something else.

Hopefully the comma is declared as a constant somewhere in Python source code (for example string._THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR), and just re-assigning it to soemthing else will do the trick.

I can not find that constant definition.

For example, one of the ways to do it now is:

```
>>> val = 123456
>>> print(f"{val:,}".replace(",", "'"))
123'456
```

The `replace` method is cumbersome and has to be repeated every time.
I also want to avoid the `locale` environment.

If the comma `,` is defined as a constant somewhere in Python source code, say for example in a module called `python_formatting_constants`, and the name of the constant was for example `THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR`, one could do:

```
>>> from python_formatting_constants import THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR
>>> THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR = "'"
>>> print(f"{val:,}") # the "," in the formatting string stays the same
123'456
>>> # but the formatted string uses the apostrophe instead of the comma
```

Comment: why do you want so badly to be able to do sth like `f"{value:'}"`? it would work only for your Python version and maintainability (especially for backwards compatibility) wouldn't be simple (you would have to remember to edit some file with each new Python version you install)

Comment: Just edited my question after your comment

Comment: Can you write a code example that after running the code what you get and what you really want.

Comment: @DataPsycho they have explained what they want pretty clearly, `print(f"{1000:,}")` -> (output) `1'000`

Comment: I have updated my question following @DataPsycho

Comment: I am not sure why you're insisting that you *not* use locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do the changes from the core of python, then you might need help from python language developers. But You can create your own format specs by creating your own class and override any provided format specs does not work for you.

```py
class MyInt(int):
    def __new__(cls, number):
        return super(MyInt, cls).__new__(cls, number)

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        if format_spec == ",":
            return format(self.value, ",").replace(",", "'")
        return format(self.value, format_spec)
```

Here I have created my own class which is a subclass of `int` and I have overloaded the `__format__` built-in method of `int` according to your need.

Example:

```
# Input
test_value = TestClass(1000)
"{:,}".format(test_value) # alternative: f"{test_value:,}"
# Output
"1'000"
```

It is just a dummy example, You can do more deep dive into format_spec argument of `__format__` method to have your own and replace any existing identifier with your own.

My suggestion will be, it will be quite easier to create your own format_spec than waiting to get some help from core python development team.

Few caveats:

If you are planning to do some add, subtract ... etc with integer and your new class, then you also have to overload all those functions for example `__add__`, `__sub__`  because any numeric operation will return pure `int` but not `MyInt` which has its own formatting.

Example:

```
# input
another_value = test_value + 2500
"{:,}".format(another_value)
# output
'3,500'
```

As you can see, the return value of `+` is a `int` but not `MyInt` so it has used `,` in the output instead. So you have to do all numeric operation beforehand and then wrap the final numeric result with the `MyInt` for just to have proper formatting.

More details about the format specs [here](https://realpython.com/python-formatted-output/).